# Datepicker doesn't work when i add PHP include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

My datepicker has no connection with the place i added this include function and non of the files are conflicting. But Datepicker function doesn't work in i add PHP include. it is working onlu when i delete my Include.

```
<input id="dob" type="text" size="8" class="form-control style_2" placeholder="">
```

Please remember these codes are not in a same place and has no any relation other than they are in same page.

```
<?php
include "assets/dts_inbound.php";
.
.
.
?>
```

Comment: there may be js files in dts_inbound.php file which may be conflicting with datepicker files

Comment: No. it is just connection to my database. it has nothing to do with any js files :(

Comment: need more debugging information from browser console. It's a long way for us to try to connect the dots between a client side UI widget and an unknown server include